# Showing that two statements involving unions of sets are equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider two sets $A,S$. For each $s\in S$, let $B_s$ denote a corresponding set.

I want to show that claims 1) and 2) are equivalent

**1)**

$A=\cup_{s\in S} B_s$

**2)**

2.1) $a\in A$ $\rightarrow$ $\exists s\in S$ s.t. $a\in B_s$

2.2) $\forall s \in S$, $B_s\subseteq A$

Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes an easy, concrete way to think about set equivalences $X = Y$ is to pick an element of $X$ and show it must be in $Y$, or vice versa.

For example, if $x \in \cup_s B_s$, that means (just by definition) that $x \in B_{s'}$ for some $s'$. By (2.2), $B_{s'} \subseteq A$, so this implies that $x \in A$. This proves that $\cup_s B_s \subset A$. You can fill in the rest of the proof similarly.